Continuity at a point via closure
I am studying general topology and a question has come to my mind.
For a map between topological spaces, the condition that the image of the closure of every subset of the domain is contained in the closure of its image (in the codomain) is known to be equivalent to global continuity (i.e. continuity at each point of the domain).
Written as such, it is a global condition, but can we make it local? viz., given a function f between topological spaces, is it true that it is continuous at a point x if and only if it maps every subset having x in its closure in a subset having f(x) in its closure?

What have you tried to prove it? At least "$\Rightarrow$" should be straightforward.

@Ulli Do you know whether the converse statement is true?

Yes, it is true. Assume, $f$ is not continuous at the point, and choose an appropriate set to violate the prerequisite.
